# IBM Worklight - App takes about 30 seconds to launch for the first time

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When I generate and install an apk build off of a Worklight project - app with Dojo and the Android environment (I've tried this with a simple one view app in both wl 5.0.6.2 and 6.0),  The first time you run the app after installing it takes about 30 seconds before you see anything. Up to that point it is a blank screen. Sometimes you get an error that the app couldn't start.  After the first launch, then the app start fast and correct every other time.

I've tested this on a number of physical Android devices. Any idea what can be done to remove this initial launch time?  Is it trying to connect to the worklight server?  Is it doing a precompile or caching on the dojo/html?

Comment: During initial Launch after install, i think the application is doing some setup work for the app, i have seen this with my apps.  This is not a dojo issue.  You will notice if you go into preferences --> apps --> your app and hit clear data. you will have the same slow response as it sets up its data again.

Comment: that is what I was thinking as well, but is there a way to minimize it.  On a s4 (quad core processor) it takes a while.

Answer (score 2):

Some questions and clarifications:

1. This is exclusive to Dojo? What happens if you create an app w/out Dojo?
   **I created a simple HTML only app and there is a slight start up difference between first run and subsequent runs (about 2 seconds).  So it looks to be dojo.**
2. Do you add anything to your project? Or just add the Dojo library (using the wizard, right?) and then let it run?
   **I'm using the standard dojo that comes with v5.  The sample program is a plain one view with a header, roundRectCategory, and a roundrectlist.  All static just to have something to show.  I have another project where I was using the OneUI from IBM.  I created the simple dojo app to remove that from the equation.**
3. What devices and Android version?
   **I ran this on a S4 and S3.  The s4 i running 4.2.2, the S3 is running 4.1.2**
4. What is the error message?
   **Unfortunatly MyApp has stopped**
5. In Worklight 6.0 there is a splash screen that should be displayed until everything has loaded. Do you see it?
   **yes, I do see that, it still sits there for a while on the initial launch**
6. There is no 5.0.6.2, please be more specific with the build numbers
   **sorry about that typo.  it is 5.0.6100.20130416-125**
7. Worklight apps by default do not connect to the server (`connectOnStartup:false` in `initOptions.js`)

Please **edit the question** with this information; I will then revise this answer (hopefully).

Comment: original edit proposal by @user2596230 but it was a bit unclean

Comment: After doing some tracing, it looks like there is a process where there are files copied to the local file system.  This is taking the lion's share of the time.  Is there a way to show a screen during this time so people won't think the program is broken or hung on initial load.

Below is a copy of the trace of an initial launch after an install of an application.  The time is proportional to the size of the resources in the project (images, javascript, html, ...).

Comment: You can show a busy indicator. BTW, I meant edit your question, not my answer.....

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about native code at this point right?